# ActionScript 3.0: moving object with delay between movements

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, actionscript, adobe

I am working on a game in which I want a movie clip to move from one random location to another, with a pause in between each movement. I have written some code with the help of some tutorials, but I can't get it to work the way I want it to. I am extremely new to ActionScript, so I'm probably doing everything wrong. Right now all my game does is pause for a certain amount of time, and then the object just jumps from one location to another extremely quickly and doesn't stop.

```
//movement of searchlight

var i:int;
for (i = 0; i < 5; i++)
{
var startTime = getTimer();

stage.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, timeDelay);

function timeDelay(event:Event):void
{
    var timePassed = getTimer();
    if (timePassed - startTime >= 5000)
    {
        moveTo();
    }
}

myObject.x = Math.round(Math.random() * 550);
myObject.y = Math.round(Math.random() * 400);
myObject.rotation = Math.round(Math.random() * 360);

// a counter that counts the current
// frame of the animation
var currentFrameCount:int;
// the total frames in the animation
var totalFrameCount:int = 20;

// the location when the animation starts
var initialX:Number;
var initialY:Number;
// the distance between the initial
// location and the destination
var distanceX:Number;
var distanceY:Number;

// when animation starts
function moveTo():void
{

    var myLocationX = Math.round(Math.random() * 550);
    var myLocationY = Math.round(Math.random() * 400);

    // the destination location 
    var destinationX:Number = myLocationX;
    var destinationY:Number = myLocationY;

    // reset frame count to 0
    currentFrameCount = 0;
    // set initial locations to the
    // current location of myObject
    initialX = myObject.x;
    initialY = myObject.y;
    // find the distance values by finding
    // the difference between initial and destination
    distanceX = destinationX - initialX;
    distanceY = destinationY - initialY;
            // set up rotation
    var initialAngle = myObject.rotation;
    var myAngleStart = Math.atan2(myLocationY-initialY,myLocationX-initialX)/(Math.PI/180);
    var myAngle = myAngleStart + 284;
    myObject.rotation = myAngle;

    // set up the enterFrame loop to 
    // animate the animation
    myObject.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, animateMoveTo);

    // handling the animation over time;
    function animateMoveTo(evt:Event):void
    {
        // each frame, increment the frame count
        // to move the animation forward
        currentFrameCount++;
        // if the frame count has not yet reached the
        // final frame of the animation, myObject
        // needs to be moved to the next location
        if (currentFrameCount < totalFrameCount)
        {
            // find the progress by comparing current frame
            // with the total frames of the animation
            var progress:Number = currentFrameCount / totalFrameCount;
            // set myObject's position to include the new
            // distance from the original location as
            // defined by the distance to the destination
            // times the progress of the animation
            myObject.x = initialX + distanceX * progress;
            myObject.y = initialY + distanceY * progress;
            myObject.rotation = initialAngle + myAngle * progress;
        }
        else
        {
            // when the animation is complete, set the
            // position of myObject to the destination
            myObject.x = destinationX;
            myObject.y = destinationY;

            // remove the enterFrame event handler so the 
            // animation ceases to run
            myObject.removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, animateMoveTo);
        }
    }
}
}
```

UPDATE: Here's what I ended up doing:

```
import com.greensock.TweenLite;

//set random starting location and rotation
myObject.x = Math.round(Math.random() * 550);
myObject.y = Math.round(Math.random() * 400);
myObject.rotation = Math.round(Math.random() * 360);

//create variables
var initialX:Number;
var initialY:Number;
var destinationX:Number;
var destinationY:Number;
var myAngleStart;
var myAngle;

//timer
var timer:Timer = new Timer( 12000 )
timer.addEventListener( TimerEvent.TIMER,rotate );
timer.start();

//function rotate
function rotate( e:TimerEvent ):void{
//set variables for current location
initialX = myObject.x
initialY = myObject.y
//set new destination
destinationX = Math.round(Math.random() * 550);
destinationY = Math.round(Math.random() * 400);
//set rotation
myAngleStart = Math.atan2(destinationY-initialY,destinationX-initialX)/(Math.PI/180);
myAngle = myAngleStart + 284;
//rotate towards new destination
TweenLite.to(myObject, 5, {rotation:myAngle, onComplete:moveTo});
}

//function moveTo
function moveTo():void {
TweenLite.to(myObject, 7, {x:destinationX, y:destinationY});
}
```

Comment: Is this code exactly how you have it in your project? I can see at least one issue with a nested function.

Comment: Can you be a little more descriptive on what effect you are trying to get?

Comment: Basically an object moves from one random location to another, and needs to be pointed in the direction it's moving. when it gets to the location, it should stop, rotate to face the next randomly generated location, and then move there (and repeat these actions continually). i haven't really coded in the rotation part correctly yet, i was mostly working at trying to get it to move to one location, stop, and then move to another, etc.

Comment: Thanks everyone, I ended up using a combination of all three answers. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, I worked on this a bit and I think this is close to what you want. The rotation doesn't work properly, but I don't have time to mess with that right now. This method is highly Dependant on frame rate. There will be problems if you tween using this method if the users framerate drops below the frame rate you have the movie set at. I set my frame rate for 30fps. I think this can set you on the right track to improving your code though:

```
    //Declare Globals
var currentFrameCount:int=0;
var totalFrameCount:int = 30;
myObject.x = Math.round(Math.random() * 550);
myObject.y = Math.round(Math.random() * 400);
var destinationX:Number = myObject.x;
var destinationY:Number = myObject.y;
var initialX:Number;
var initialY:Number;
var distanceX:Number;
var distanceY:Number;
var xProg:Number;
var yProg:Number;
var myAngleChange;
var myAngleEnd;
var initialAngle;

var countFrame:int = 0;
var delay:int = 0;

addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME,callDelay);
function callDelay(e:Event){
        countFrame++;
        delayEvent(delay);
}
//Code to move the object to a random location and give it a random target to move to.
function spawnObject(){
        myObject.rotation = Math.round(Math.random() * 360);//random rotation
        initialAngle = myObject.rotation;
        destinationX = Math.round(Math.random() * 550);//random destination
        destinationY = Math.round(Math.random() * 400);
        currentFrameCount = 0;
        initialX = myObject.x;
        initialY = myObject.y;
        distanceX = destinationX - initialX;//distance between destination and initial
        distanceY = destinationY - initialY;
        initialAngle = myObject.rotation;//buggy rotation code
        myAngleEnd = Math.atan2(destinationY-initialY,destinationX-initialX)/(Math.PI/180);
        myAngleChange = (initialAngle - myAngleEnd)/totalFrameCount;
        xProg = distanceX/totalFrameCount;//amount to increase by each frame
        yProg = distanceY/totalFrameCount;
}


function delayEvent(period){
        if ( (countFrame) >= period){
                removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME,callDelay);
                timedEvent();
                countFrame=0;
                return;
        }

}


function timedEvent ():void
{
                currentFrameCount = totalFrameCount;
                myObject.x = destinationX;
                myObject.y = destinationY;
                spawnObject();//move the object to a new location and give new destination
                myObject.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME,moveTo);//add an event listener to move the object around
}

function moveTo(e:Event):void
{
                myObject.rotation += myAngleChange; //increase rotation by the rotation step value (buggy)
        currentFrameCount++;
        if (currentFrameCount < totalFrameCount)
        { 
            myObject.x += xProg;//incrase x by the x step value
            myObject.y += yProg;//increase y by the y step value
        }
        else
        {
            myObject.removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, moveTo);// remvoe this event listener
                        addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME,callDelay);
        }
}
```

Comment: The jitter is probably due to the for loop

Answer (score 2):

You should look into one of the many convenient Tweening engines, such as [TweenLite](http://www.greensock.com/tweenlite/) or [Tweener](http://code.google.com/p/tweener/).  They make this sort of thing very easy.

Comment: The code posted in other responses is probably very useful to have, for people that want to learn about how to do a tween. But, given the admission of being extremely new to actionscript and using some tutorial code. ("frankencoding" as I call it.) I would strongly suggest using one of the tween engines listed here. They really are quite robust for most uses.

Comment: @prototypical +1.  By suggesting the use of one of the tween engines, I'm not trying to knock any of the detailed answers to the question at all and I agree that it's very useful knowledge to have.

Answer (score 1):

If you are just looking to move an object at set intervals just use this

```
var timer:Timer = new Timer( 1000 )
timer.addEventListener( TimerEvent.TIMER,moveTo );
timer.start();

function moveTo( e:TimerEvent ):void{
    myObject.x = Math.round(Math.random() * 550);
    myObject.y = Math.round(Math.random() * 400);
}
```